# what does this function do in detail?

Tags: java, model, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

```
public static Finder<Long,Task> find = new Finder<Long,Task>(
       Long.class, Task.class
);
```

this is a function of a model in Playframework using EBean Model superclass. i dont understand this function in detail, what does it do actually?

Comment: It's not a function, it's a function call (specifically, it's a call to a constructor), whose result is assigned to the static member variable called `find`.

Comment: oh okay. so what is the purpose?

Comment: If you want to know what a `Finder` does, I'd suggest looking at the documentation (because I'm not familiar with this framework).  If you want to know *why* it's being assigned to `find`, well, you'll have to ask the author of this code!

Comment: sorry for dumb question!!! please dont downvote!

Comment: Don't worry, next time you'll earn 5 UPvotes ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finder is used to look up entities by primary key.Task is the entity here, it was persisted with a primary key of Long, it's Id

Doc for Finder:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.1/java/play/db/ebean/Model.Finder.html

Your snippet, explained:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaEbean

Answer (score 1):

Its generic code.
 are placeholders for intern variables, which are generalised, so you can use it for other classes aswell. Long.class means, that he gets the class and can generate new instances of the classes, with generic code.
So the function needs to create instances of the classes your working with, but don't ask me why :P
If you wanna know what the function actually does, theres always an API for that